# Project.json structure for debugging source of NuGet package

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget, visual-studio-debugging, dnx

I am having trouble debugging the code of a NuGet package in Visual Studio, my directory structure for the library/NuGet package is as follows:

- ProjectName.Core

  - src/ProjectName.Core

    - project.json
    - /* .cs files etc. */
  - global.json

And my second project that references the above ProjectName.Core:

- ProjectName.App

  - src/ProjectName.App

    - project.json
    - /* .cs files etc. */
  - global.json

I have published the ProjectName.Core package and I can reference it in my ProjectName.App project.json file like so:

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "description": "App",

    "commands": {
        "run": "run"
    },

    "frameworks": {
        "dnx46": {
            "frameworkAssemblies": {
                "System.DirectoryServices": "4.0.0.0",
                "System.Management": "4.0.0.0",
                "System.Runtime": "4.0.20.0",
                "System.Collections": "4.0.10.0"
            }
        }
    },

    "dependencies": {
        "ProjectName.Core": "1.0.0"
    }
}
```

Both global.json files in ProjectName.Core and ProjectName.App look like this:

```
{
    "projects": [
        "src",
        "tests"
    ]
}
```

However since ProjectName.Core is a "class library" I can't debug into the code and step through it when I start the debugger on ProjectName.App. How can I debug code in the ProjectName.Core library without having to commit the code to Git then wait for TeamCity to update my NuGet package feed and then have ProjectName.App restore ProjectName.Core to the latest version?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, in ProjectName.App's global.json file I had to change it to the following:

```
{
    "projects": [
        "src",
        "tests",
        "../ProjectName.Core/src"
    ]
}
```

I can now see both projects in Visual Studio and debug through both.